# Algorithm for filtering and grouping geological points

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have some geological points with following distribution:
[image: Initial Points]

I need an algorithm to filter desultory/single points and to group points which are adjacent. 
I require the algorithm create something like the following from above points for me
[image: After Applying Algorithm]

So after applying algorithm on first figure, I need three conglomerate of points, each one known as a critical section, be generated. (like figure 2)

I know some algorithms including Graph Partition, Convex Hull, Polygon Partitioning algorithms, but no one is typically suitable for this problem.

Do you know any specified algorithm for this question?

Comment: Can't see those images you link to.

Comment: still can't see the images, it shows only ads of a hosting

Comment: Completely changed the links. It goes well apparently now

Comment: I don't see any difference in the two images. But did you look at density based clustering?

Comment: I embeded images in the post, I think the issues are removed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like a typical example case for **density based clustering** to me.

Look up DBSCAN on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

To create a 3 clusters or centroids from any number of points, you the method of K-means. You may get a great solution without removing any outliers.

https://github.com/reddavis/K-Means

If you want to remove outliers, you will need to iteratively remove each to point and re-calculate K-Means to see which points are the most influential and create the most error. Be careful. This part is difficult because the sequence at which you remove the points matters as much as the points themselves. The concepts behind Cook's Distance for least squares regression may inspire your thinking.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook's_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance)

Good luck! Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks, I will study it surely. did you saw the links I put on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to compute a [minimum spanning tree](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/minimum-spanning-tree.shtml) and remove its longest edges in order to split your set into clusters.

Comment: How a minimum spanning tree could help me in this situation? What about filtration process?

Comment: @DaveQorashi: Compute MST and remove all longest edges. Then use the center of each subtree for a K-Means. It's a way to find good center value for k-means.